# Error: node_modules/preact/src/jsx.d.ts:2138:24 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SVGMPathElement'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, preact

The project is based on Angular , I am getting this error when check in few typescript classes , However it worked well in previous script , In both cases package.json was not checked in , Its strange.

Let me know if anyone has an idea how to solve , I will be providing details.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same issue on my end. I fixed the issue by adding Preact as a dependency and using version `10.12.1`. Seems like a new version of Preact was released a couple days ago and it's causing issues.

Edit: I should also mention that I used `yarn` to install dependencies and used the `resolutions` field in package.json as follows:

```json
"resolutions": {
    "preact": "10.12.1"
}
```

Comment: also need to add    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "paths": {
      "react": [ "./node_modules/preact/compat/" ],
      "react-dom": [ "./node_modules/preact/compat/" ]
    }  in tsconfig.json

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI If you're using Angular, adding the React -> Preact TS aliases will do absolutely nothing.